# Forward to JSP within Spring Controller after form submission

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp

Using Spring `@Controller`, `@RequestMapping` and `@ModelAttribute`, I'd like to achieve a basic form submission flow in which the user is forwarded to a new JSP with attributes set. Spring provides different ways to achieve this, but I have received various errors.

**Example 1**
Based on tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial

*form.html*

```html
<form action="/submitForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text"id="field1" name="field1">
    <!-- other input fields -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

*success.jsp*

```
<p>Thanks for signing up ${userName}!!</p>
```

*MyController.java*

```java
@Controller
public class MyController{

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/submitForm", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public String post(@ModelAttribute SignupRequest request, ModelMap model){
        // At this point, the SignupRequest is populated correctly 
        model.addAttribute("userName", request.getUserName());

        return "success";
    }
}
```

**Results**

1. Using `return "success"` - the result is *HTTP 404 Not Found*
2. Using `return "success.jsp"`, the result is *HTTP 405 Request method
   'POST' not supported*
3. Using `return "redirect:/success.jsp"`, the client is redirected,
   but attributes are not set, and ${userName} is visible.

**Example 2**
Based on the accepted answer here: [Redirect after POST method in spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050017/redirect-after-post-method-in-spring-mvc)

*MyController.java*

```java
@Controller
public class MyController{

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/submitForm", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public ModelAndView post(@ModelAttribute SignupRequest request){
        // At this point, the SignupRequest is populated correctly 

        ModelAndView mAV = new ModelAndView("redirect:/success.jsp");
        mAV.addObject("userName", request.getUserName());

        return mAV;
    }
}
```

**Result**
the client is redirected, but attributes are not set, and ${userName} is visible.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Additional details
Using SpringBoot with embedded Tomcat. JSP file located in `src>main>resources>public`. The raw JSP is being served. I believe the project is not treating JSP as it should. Adding POM deps.

```xml
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Controller
public class MyController{

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/submitForm", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    public RedirectView post(@ModelAttribute SignupRequest request, RedirectAttributes ra){
        // At this point, the SignupRequest is populated correctly 

        RedirectView rw = new RedirectView();
        rw.setUrl("success.jsp");
        ra.addFlashAttribute("userName", request.getUserName());

        return rw;
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in the same behavior, the JSP file itself is served up without the attributes rendered. Please see my edits to the question, I think the problem is not with the controller, but the project itself. It's not rendering JSP.

Comment: is there no error or exception thrown? Does it work if you keep the excluded `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and remove the `jetty` plugin? Did you register a jsp view resolver?

Comment: There is no exception or error, the JSP file itself is rendered. I've configured a view resolver based on this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial. The result is my other static content not being served, with HTTP 404.

Comment: static resources need to be configured as well: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Comment: Thanks. But does this not add additional resource usage if I want those other files to be simply static files? The static files are already served properly, seems my issue is I want to enable but static files as well as a controller for a JSP file.

Comment: I got lost, I would have to see the whole project to figure this out