# Redirect ModelAndView with message

Tags: java, html, spring

My application has a method to update a conference. After doing so I have a modelandview with a redirect to the main conference list. This all works fine although the message which I add as an object to the modelandview does not display.

My method in my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/updateConference")
public ModelAndView updateConference(
        @ModelAttribute("conference") @Valid ConferenceDto conferenceDto, BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return new ModelAndView("updateConference","conferenceDto", conferenceDto);
    }

    try {
        conferenceService.updateConference(conferenceDto);
    } catch (ConferenceAlreadyExistException uaeEx) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("updateConference","conferenceDto", conferenceDto);
        mav.addObject("message", uaeEx.getMessage());
        return mav;
    }
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/teacher/configure"); // Problem is here
    mav.addObject("message", "Successfully modified conference.");
    return mav;
}
```

In my html I have the line:

```
<div  th:if="${message != null}" th:align="center" class="alert alert-info" th:utext="${message}">message</div>
```

After updating the conference it goes back to configure.html although the message does not show. In the url I can see *http://localhost:8080/teacher/configure?message=Successfully+modified+conference*

I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050017/redirect-after-post-method-in-spring-mvc/52051131) although it did not help.

I tried to experiment by setting *ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("configure")* and the message displays but my conference list is empty and the url is http://localhost:8080/teacher/updateconference

Any tips is highly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have tried to use RedirectAttributes as *crizzis* pointed out & [this page](https://gerrytan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/preserving-validation-error-messages-on-spring-mvc-form-post-redirect-get/) and have this now:

```
 @PostMapping("/updateConference")
    public String updateConference(
            @ModelAttribute("conference") @Valid ConferenceDto conferenceDto, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.conferenceDto", result);
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("conferenceDto", conferenceDto);
            return "redirect:/teacher/updateConference";
        }

        try {
            conferenceService.updateConference(conferenceDto);
        } catch (ConferenceAlreadyExistException uaeEx) {
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("conferenceDto", conferenceDto);
            attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", uaeEx.getMessage());
            return "redirect:/teacher/updateConference";
        }
        attributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Successfully modified conference.");
        return "redirect:/teacher/configure";
    }
```

My get method:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/updateConference/{id}")
public String showUpdateConferenceForm(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id, Model model){
    Optional<Conference> conference = conferenceService.findById(id);
    if (!model.containsAttribute("ConferenceDto")) {
        model.addAttribute("conference", new ConferenceDto());
    }
    return "updateConference";
}
```

This works as intended and my message is shown on my configure.html . However, when I have an error in BindingResults the application goes to an error page and I get this in the console:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-web-flash-attributes

Comment: maybe try `${#request.getParameter('message')`

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I am trying to do RedirectAttributes way and it works as intended. The message is passed and it shows. Although theres something wrong with my GET method as it does not show binding result and goes to an error page. I will update my question with the implemented methods that I try to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RedirectAttributes` which has `addFlashAttribute` method. You can set the `success` or `failure` message like you did and access that message through the key in the redirected page as you need.

when the error occurs you are redirecting to the same method instead of this you can just render the template in case there is error. I do this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to use RedirectAttributes. Could you please elaborate on rendering the template with a quick example? I don't really understand

Comment: if the form submission is failed like there is some kind of validation errors then render the form i.e. the template where you can show the errors with submitted values and if there is no error then redirect. you can also redirect to the url which renders the form in case of error related to from validation but you may loose the values the user submitted and the validation errors as well. in your code you are redirecting to post method itself and the redirect is by nature submits `get` request to the provided url where your method only accepts `post` request.

Comment: Oh I see, so I modified from `return "redirect:/teacher/updateConference";` to `return "updateConference";`. All works well now. I am marking your answer as accepted. Thanks!